# Sorting an NSArray in reverse order

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

```
NSArray* sortedArray = [myArray sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(compare:)];
```

Just wondering how I can sort this array of numbers in descending order?

Comment: Good question. I didn't know that one.

Comment: ^Why is a comment stating "Idk" receiving upvotes? Ah what the hell, I'm joining in +1

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Either use the method that allows you to pass a block as a comparator and implement a comparator that reverses the objects (returns NSOrderedAscending for NSOrderedDescending and vice versa)....

... or:

```
NSArray *reversed = [[[myArray sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(compare:)] reverseObjectEnumerator] allObjects];
```

Sorry.  Derped the most important part.

Comment: The comment with no code is reasonable but the line of code given in this answer simply reverses the array. No sorting is actually being done. It would be better to clearly state that this should be called on the sorted array.

Comment: Yerp.  I derped the original expression.

Answer (score 8):

Use `NSSortDescriptor`

```
NSSortDescriptor* sortOrder = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey: @"self" ascending: NO];
NSArray *temp = [myArray sortedArrayUsingDescriptors: [NSArray arrayWithObject: sortOrder]];
```

Answer (score 0):

I like to use the `sortedArrayUsingFunction:` method which gives full control of how the array is sorted. Then to reverse the results return the negative value of what you would have returned.

```
NSInteger myCompare (id obj1, id obj2, void *context) {
    int retval = [obj1 compare:obj2 options:NSNumericSearch];
    retval = -retval; // now it's sorted reverse
    return retval;
}

...

NSArray *arr = @[@"foo20zz", @"foo7zz", @"foo100zz"];
NSArray *sarr = [arr sortedArrayUsingFunction:myCompare context:NULL];
NSLog(@"sarr is %@", sarr);
```